# New Controller Code Generation in Grails

Tags: grails-controller

when using Grails for generating code in Controllers a want to know what this code is doing:

> **'*' { respond eroVCdtCallDetailsInstance, [status: CREATED] }**

```
request.withFormat {
                form multipartForm {
                    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'eroVCdtCallDetails.label', default: 'EroVCdtCallDetails'), eroVCdtCallDetailsInstance.id])
                    redirect eroVCdtCallDetailsInstance
                }
                '*' { respond eroVCdtCallDetailsInstance, [status: CREATED] }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried to google this topic? [link](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/respond.html)

Comment: I have seen on other posts what this code is doing '*' { respond eroVCdtCallDetailsInstance, [status: CREATED] }, but a don't understand Syntax. Why there is not dot between '*' and closure and why there is not defined any function which is aceppting closure as Argument. General case of using closure is like this someInstanceObject.function(Closure).